# Is there a way to coerce a numpy Array created in C into a MaskedArray?

Tags: numpy

I want to create a numpy.mp.MaskedArray in C using data that already exists.  I can create a numpy.Array like this:

```
PyObject *arr = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(...)
```

But I want the object that gets presented to library users to be a MaskedArray (subclass of Array), rather than an Array.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Most if not all of the code that sybclasses MA is Python, not compiled.  A MA has a regular array `data` attribute, plus a boolean array `mask` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-answering:

```
// Create the numpy array
PyObject *arr = PyArray_NewFromDescr(&PyArray_Type, descr, 1,
        &longCount, &pointSize, data, NPY_ARRAY_WRITEABLE, nullptr);

// Wrap the created array in a MaskedArray.
PyObject *module = PyImport_ImportModule("numpy.ma");
PyObject *dict = PyModule_GetDict(module);
PyObject *o = PyDict_GetItemString(dict, "MaskedArray");

PyObject *args = PyTuple_New(1);
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, arr);

m_directArray = PyObject_CallObject(o, args);
```